# How close can I make this button in CSS3?

Tags: css

[image: Sign Up Now Button]

I can't seem to mimic the 1px line -1px from the top. Don't worry about the Arrow.

Top Color: #f78c84
Bottom Color: #c85b53
1px Line: #ffbcb6

There is also a box-shadow that I can't get perfect.

Comment: Check this online button generator - [css3button generator](http://css3button.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is an inset box shadow of  with vertical offset 1, no blur, no spread:

```
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5M8d/4/) (with not quite correct colors).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is there anyway to change the rgba into hex?

Comment: @AndB not, if you want to have transparency. If you have equivalent hex colors, just use them. If you want transparency, you have to use rgba (which is very well supported nowadays). `rgba(255,255,255,0.7)` could be something like `#fdd`.